# React not re-rendering within if-else statement

Tags: reactjs

I have the following action:

```
export const receiveBillingRun = data => ({
    type: RECEIVE_BILLING_RUN,
    data,
}); 

export const retrieveBillingRun = billingRunId => dispatch => {
    $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: `/api/billing/billingruns/${billingRunId}/`}).done(data => {
            dispatch(receiveBillingRun(data));
        }
    );
}
```

in reducer I am setting the `billingRun` and `invoice` to state

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    billingRun: action.data,
    invoice: action.data.invoice
});
```

I have a component has its property mapped to the `invoice` object:

```
export default connect(
    (...
     invoice,
    ...),
    (...
     retrieveBillingRun,
     ...)
)(Component);
```

I have the following method to perform an API call and refresh the billingRun:

```
writeToTigerPaw(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/billing/telecom/write-to-system/',
        data: {account_number: this.props.params.accountNumber, invoice: this.props.invoice.id}
    }).done(this.props.retrieveBillingRun(this.props.params.billingRunId))
}
```

The above code works as expected and the component refreshes with the latest status of the invoice.

But after I added a confirmation check as below:

```
writeToTigerPaw(){
    const isconfirmed = confirm("Are you sure to write to system?");
    if (isconfirmed === true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/billing/telecom/write-to-system/',
            data: {account_number: this.props.params.accountNumber, invoice: this.props.invoice.id}
        }).done(this.props.retrieveBillingRun(this.props.params.billingRunId))
    }
}
```

The API called was actually triggered and changed the status, however the component didn't refresh to reflect the latest state.

**UPDATE:**

I suspect it was how I passed the argument in `done`, the way I did before was executing it immediately? After putting it in an arrow function seems to have fixed it.

```
writeToTigerPaw(){
    const isconfirmed = confirm("Are you sure to write to TigerPaw?");
    if (isconfirmed === true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/billing/truebill/write-to-tp/',
            data: {account_number: this.props.params.accountNumber, invoice: this.props.invoice.id}
        }).done(()=> this.props.retrieveBillingRun(this.props.params.billingRunId))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that literally the only change to the code? The `if` and `confirm()`?

Comment: @LeelandMiller yeah, I am scratching my head...

Comment: Is the redux state updated? Can you check if `retrieveBillingInfo` is actually dispatched and the redux state is updated? You can use redux dev-tools for checking this.

Comment: I added some console logs within the reducer, and I saw it gets triggered, but the invoice object was not changed.

Comment: Looks like you didn't bind this function writeToTigerPaw. Bind it in constructor and hopefully it would work

Comment: I just noticed that it was trying to fetch the status before posting to the API, but I don't know why that would happen...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `componentDidUpdate` and compare `prevProps.invoice` to your current `props.invoice`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Within componentDidUpdate, the invoice didn't get changed... But if I refresh the page, the component shows the latest change.